# Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal C#?

Tags: c#

Hola a todos tengo un problema,
Intento copiar una linea seleccionada del ListView al Clipboard.
y luego agrego esa linea a ContextMenuStrip para que muestre la linea seleccionada. hasta ahí esta todo bien. pero no la copia al ClipBoard.

alguna sugerencia? gracias totales..

´´´
//Código

```
        private void listViewContenido_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
                int Position = listViewContenido.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).Item.Index;
                if (Position > -1)
                {
                    Copiar = listViewContenido.Items[Position].ToString();
                    menu.Items.Add(Copiar + "  Nº " + Position);
                }
                menu.Show(listViewContenido, e.X, e.Y);
                menu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(MenuClick);
           
            }
        }

        private void MenuClick(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text.ToString() == Copiar)
            {
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < listViewContenido.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    buffer.Append(listViewContenido.Columns[i].Text);
                    buffer.Append("\t");
                }

                buffer.Append("\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < listViewContenido.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < listViewContenido.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                    
buffer.Append(listViewContenido.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text);
                        buffer.Append("\t");
                    }

                    buffer.Append("\n");
                }

                Clipboard.SetText(buffer.ToString());

            }
        }
```

Comment: Corrijo : es  ``` if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) ```  :)

Comment: Click en "Editar" y actualiza la pregunta. La zona de comentarios tiene otra función. Saludos :D

Comment: Intenta suscribir al evento directamente `menu.ItemClicked += MenuClick`

Comment: Te faltan las comillas en `e.ClickedItem.Text.ToString() == Copiar`. Por cierto, `e.ClickedItem.Text` ya es un string. No necesitas llamar a `ToString`. Así te quedaría corregido `e.ClickedItem.Text == "Copiar"`

Comment: Copiar es un string bro  Copiar = listViewContenido.Items[Position].ToString(); por eso no lleva comillas

Comment: probe con esto :         private void MenuClick(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Id = e.ClickedItem.Text.ToString();

            if (Id.Contains(Copiar))
            {

Comment: pero ahora me copia todo el texto de ListViw. y solo quiero el item seleccionado. Y el ToString es por que agrego un Int desde otra Clase